# Passing Parameter from SSRS dataset to Snowflake

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to pass parameters from SSRS dataset to Snowflake.Previously I am connecting SSRS to SqlServer DB and passing parameter as @client_id.I want to move queries to run on snowflake.But i don't know how to pass parameter to query.

When I use standard parameters against Snowflake I get

> > syntax error @client_id is unexpected

Comment: What happens when you try what you have? Depending on your data size, you can always parameterise it at the SSRS report server (but this is generally not recommended)

Comment: So we don't actually have information that parameters don't function (you didn't try it) but a quick google search turned up this method to build literal strings with expressions. Please try something and post back a specific question. https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00007DAa4MSAT/has-anyone-use-snowflake-as-datasource-for-mssql-ssrs-report-if-you-do-how-to-pass-a-vaiable-to-snowsql-from-ssrs

Comment: I am getting syntax error @client_id is unexpected.I am trying different things from today morning and searching for information.I tried the link that you provided today afternoon and only SQL can be added in dataset .I am trying to know how to pass query  as string from SSRS dataset.

Comment: In future questions please describe what you tried and what happened. (note my edit)

Comment: Is this the process you are using to add a filter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-a-filter-to-a-dataset-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#to-add-a-filter-to-an-embedded-dataset-or-a-shared-dataset-instance

Comment: It should be this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/associate-a-query-parameter-with-a-report-parameter-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

="SELECT DIVISION, DEPARTMENT, CLASS FROM ACCESSLAYER.DIM_PRODUCT WHERE DIVISION IN ('"+Parameters!P_Division.Value+"');"

[image]